# JavaScript: Equivalent of arrow function (how to not use an arrow)

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrow-functions

I am new to JavaScript, and I am struggling with how to change an arrow function with non-arrow function... Please help, and thank you very much in advance!

```
this.middleware(req,res,()=>{
    this.processRoutes(req,res);
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how you can do it.

```
this.middleware = function(req,res) {
  this.processRoutes(req,res);
};
```

However you should use arrow function unless you have any specific reason for not to use it.

Comment: This is not at all equivalent to the OPs code